# Li-SoCl2 battery state of charge

Tags: batteries, measurement, discharge, lithium

I'm developing a data logger powered by Li-SoCl2 (http://www.100y.com.tw/pdf_file/02-SAFT-LS33600.pdf) battery and I have no idea on how to overcome the problem of estimating the residual charge of the cells.
The discharge voltage curve is so flat and also changes with temperature (on board I have a very precise temperature reading).

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Can you try coulomb counting? (current * time = charge, and you know how much charge you can pull out of the battery before it dies)

Comment: The curve is indeed flat, but at the end of the charge it doesn't drop so slowly you wouldn't notice with time to spare. Perhaps you can make do with just an early depletion warning? Coulomb counting is only good for rates within hours or days; it would not be precise enough if your battery is to last longer. However, a characterization of your design consumption plus a voltage check could be enough. What is your circuit's average current draw?